# What to do if the process costs 100% but the restore window does not close?

Tags: sql-server

For half an hour the restore database is 100% but the restore window does not close. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wait.

This is very well explained in [SQL Server Mysteries: The Case of the Not 100% RESTORE…](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bobsql/2017/04/25/sql-server-mysteries-the-case-of-the-not-100-restore-2/):

> Wow. That was quite a bit just to show you how a RESTORE can take longer to complete “than you expect” and why 100% doesn’t necessarily mean 100% complete with the entire RESTORE process. A few closing thoughts:
>
> 1. The % process messages are only for the copying of database pages from the backup to database files. You can see their byte progress more in the XEvent trace. I suspect we do this because the copy process is a more predictable process we determine a “% complete” progress
> 2. The BACKUPIO subprocess task writes to the tlog as seen in the XEvent trace after the log is zeroed because that is where we copy in the log pages from the log portion of the backup. That does use “normal” I/O routines so will show up in async_io and file write events.
> 3. It is very possible that other scenarios I mentioned earlier regarding the transaction log (copying in the log blocks, going through VLFs, and running recovery) can make the completion take even long past the 100% mark because we wouldn’t try these operations until all the database pages are copied to the database files. Now you know though how to use XEvent to determine which part of applying the log could be taking extra time.